# why isn't a recomposition happening when the state is changed in the viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i have this code where i have a parent component QuranScreen and child component PagesContainer, the child component contains a horizontal pager inside it, whenever the pager state is changed (page changed), i emit an event to parent and change the currentPage state from the viewModel, this is supposed to cause a recomposition, but nothing happens..especially in the inner components (pagesContainer, benefits and Youtube screen), why is that happening?

```
@Composable
fun QuranScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    pageNum: String?,
    quranViewModel: QuranViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    if (pageNum != null) {
        quranViewModel.currentPage = pageNum
    };
    val currentPage = quranViewModel.currentPage;
    val page = quranViewModel.quranData.get(Integer.parseInt(currentPage) - 1)
    val selectedTab = quranViewModel.selectedTab

    Column {
        
        when (selectedTab) {
            "page" -> PagesContainer(quranViewModel.quranData, currentPage) { newPage ->
                println("changing viewmodel page to " + newPage) //gives correct output
                quranViewModel.currentPage = newPage
            }
            "benefits" -> Benefits(page.benefits, page.pageNum)
            "yt" -> YouTube(page.ytLink.split("v=").last())
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagesContainer(
    quranData: List<QuranPage>,
    pageNum: String?,
    onPageChanged: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = Integer.parseInt(pageNum) - 1,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
    ) {
        quranData.size
    }

    LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
        snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
            Log.d("Page change", "Page changed to $page")
            onPageChanged("${page + 1}")
        }
    }


    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            key = { quranData[it].pageNum },
            pageSize = PageSize.Fill
        ) { index ->
            SinglePage(quranData[index].pageNum)
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: Viewmodel code

```
class QuranViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val quranData: List<QuranPage> = QuranStore.getQuranData();
    private var _selectedTab by mutableStateOf("page")
    var selectedTab:String
        get() = this._selectedTab
        set(value){this._selectedTab=value}

    private var _currentPage by mutableStateOf("1")
    var currentPage:String
        get() = this._currentPage
        set(value){this._currentPage=value}
}
```

Edit 2: i'm delving deeper into the issue and i logged the changes that happen inside my viewmodel, the recomposition does happen but the state value is then returned to the original value, i can't use remember inside viewmodel so i don't know how exactly can i fix this. there is another point i'm suspecting that is i'm sending the original pageNum in a route parameter that leads to this screen which might be getting reset with each recomposition..i don't have a way around this either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recomposition would be triggered if a state value changes from the scope of a state hoisting Composable (in your case the `QuranScreen` should be state hoisting but you are not declaring the variables are states.

You can use remember and change them to something like:

```
@Composable
fun QuranScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    pageNum: String?,
    quranViewModel: QuranViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val quranData by quranViewModel.quranData.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val selectedTab by quranViewModel.selectedTab.collectAsState(initial = "page")
    val currentPage by quranViewModel.currentPage.collectAsState(initial = "1")

    when (selectedTab) {
        "page" -> PagesContainer(quranData, currentPage) { newPage ->
            quranViewModel.setCurrentPage(newPage)
        }
        "benefits" -> {
            val page = quranData.getOrNull(Integer.parseInt(currentPage) - 1)
            if (page != null) {
                Benefits(page.benefits, page.pageNum)
            }
        }
        "yt" -> {
            val page = quranData.getOrNull(Integer.parseInt(currentPage) - 1)
            if (page != null) {
                YouTube(page.ytLink.split("v=").last())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you'd need to also change the `ViewModel` to expose these values as `StateFlow`s to be `collectedAsState`:

```
class QuranViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _quranData = MutableStateFlow(QuranStore.getQuranData())
    val quranData: StateFlow<List<QuranPage>> = _quranData.asStateFlow()

    private val _selectedTab = MutableStateFlow("page")
    val selectedTab: StateFlow<String> = _selectedTab.asStateFlow()

    private val _currentPage = MutableStateFlow("1")
    val currentPage: StateFlow<String> = _currentPage.asStateFlow()

    fun setSelectedTab(value: String) {
        _selectedTab.value = value
    }

    fun setCurrentPage(value: String) {
        _currentPage.value = value
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest you to try and simplify the state in just one data class since they seem to make sense to be updated together but I'm not sure it would be the best way.

Now, when the `onPageChanged` lambda is invoked, the `QuranViewModel` will update its state flows accordingly and the `collectAsState` will be observing this new emitted value, thus triggering a new composition with the most recent values.

Comment: oh so all i had to do was change the normal state to a stateflow and collect it. your solution works like a charm. thank you very much

Comment: @cesonha Can you please explain how it's worked just converting mutableState to StateFlow and collectAsState in composeable function. As per my understanding any value change the in mutableState the occur recomposition.

Comment: hey @DarshanMistry after your comment and rereading both the question and Phil's answer I think have an idea, I guess it is regarding the custom getter the original viewModel implementation had, but I'll confirm it better and properly edit my answer if needed to add more context and a possible easier solution

Answer (score 2):

First problem is in thess lines:

```
if (pageNum != null) {
    quranViewModel.currentPage = pageNum
}
```

this code will be executed on each recomposition, so your data will be overriden. You need to use `LaunchedEffect`:

```
LaunchedEffect(pageNum) {
    if (pageNum != null) {
        quranViewModel.currentPage = pageNum
    }
}
```

Note that it still can be reset on configuration changes, e.g. rotation. You can use `rememberSaveable` to save flag, or use a separate component, like [`SaveableLaunchedEffect`](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/38d17370e5156b6a6eac31f55e13da3f).

---

Your view model structure is perfectly legal and causes recompositions as expected.

The problem is that you don't use the updated value anywhere that you could have noticed.

So you update `quranViewModel.currentPage`, and the only place you read this value is passing it with `currentPage` into the `pageNum` parameter, and then using this parameter to pass it into `initialPage`.

`initialPage` is not expected to react to new data, that's clear from the name, so there's no way your change will change your screen layout.

The easiest way to check if you're having recomposition or not is to add a log - and the following one works fine to me:

```
println("recomposed ${pageNum}")
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
//...
```

So you have a problem with your logic - maybe you need to pass `pageNum` to `SinglePage`, or you need a different parameter - not sure what you expect to happen with this parameter change.

---

A note about your code. Using `mutableStateOf` in the view model is perfectly legal, you don't need to use `MutableStateFlow` if you just need to store value. Personally, I only use flows when I need to use the flow functionality, e.g. combine/debounce/etc, or if it should be watched from non Compose layers.

But I'm not sure what the point of creating `_currentPage` is, since your code:

```
private var _currentPage by mutableStateOf("1")
var currentPage:String
    get() = this._currentPage
    set(value){this._currentPage=value}
```

is completely equivalent to:

var currentPage by mutableStateOf("1")

If you need to add more logic to the setter, you can make it private and update the value with a function:

```
var currentPage by mutableStateOf("1")
    private set

fun onChangeCurrentPage(newValue: String) {
    currentPage = newValue
}
```

Comment: Still scratch my head how accepted answer is worked just convert mutableState to StateFlow. If you know reason can please explain.

Comment: @DarshanMistry it doesn't have `quranViewModel.currentPage = pageNum`, it may be more obvious to pass `collectAsState(initial = pageNum)` to get author's desired result - but it also will be reset on configuration change, same as with `LaunchedEffect`

Answer (score 0):

you did note share your viewmodel make sure you use mutableStateOf

```
class QuranViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var currentPage by mutableStateOf("1") 
}
```

Comment: just added the viewmodel code, yes i included the line you mentioned
    private var _currentPage by mutableStateOf("1")